# Google Ads Remarketing defers click (Tag still running) if consent is denied via consent mode

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager

I found a nasty delay before navigation on clicks if a custom parameter is used (in that case "select_item") as a custom event on a click (in my case a click on a product list item) if the consent via consent mode is denied. As soon as the consent is granted, the click and therefore the navigation happens immediately. The "Remarketing Tag" also stays in the firing status "Still running".

This event also triggers a GA4 event which is working as expected with consent granted and denied.

I created a workaround with a manual exception on that trigger that the Datalayervariable of my consent manager is additionally queried on that event and the tag not executed if set to false. I wanted to ask if someone else experienced the same behaviour and if there is something i maybe have overseen to solve that issue.

Setup (Wordpress + Woocommerce + Plugin GTM4WP + Google Remarketing Tag triggering on certain events)